# How to determine if the terminal is a windows terminal

Tags: shell, command-line, environment-variables, windows-terminal

How to determine if the terminal is a windows terminal.

I want to enabled ANSI output in windows terminal and disenabled in CMD.

Is it possible to judge through environmental variables? like：

- `ANSICON` in https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon
- `ConEmuANSI` in https://conemu.github.io/en/ConEmuEnvironment.html

What is the best practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the environment variables `WT_PROFILE_ID` or `WT_SESSION` are present.